# Number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers such that $(a+ib)^{2008}=a-ib$ holds good is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Number of ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers such that
>   $(a+ib)^{2008}=a-ib$ holds good is?

I tried like $(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i{\tan^{-1}(\dfrac ba)}})^{2008}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}e^{i\tan (\frac{-b}{a})}$.But after this what to do?

Comment: If $z=a+ib$ then $|z|^{2008}=|z|$ so $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$

Answer (score 6):

If $z=a+ib$ then $|z|^{2008}=|z|$ so $|z|=0$ or $|z|=1$. If $z \ne 0$ then $|z|=1$ and from $z^{2008}=\bar z$ equivalent $z^{2008}= \frac 1 z$ we get $z^{2009}=1$. We have found 2009 solutions and, by adding zero, the result is 2010.

Comment: How did you get $z^{2009}=1$ from $|z|=1|$ ?

Comment: @ZOZ See my updated answer